# Interacting with Get-WmiObject via .NET core

Tags: powershell, .net-core, get-wmiobject, powershell-6.0

I need to get information about system. I can get it from Get-WmiObject with Powershell. But I need to gather it with .NET core application.

I'm able to execute some basic commands like Get-Command or Get-Process.

When i try to exexute Get-WmiObject, i have this error

> The term 'Get-WmiObject' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Same issue with this command using (Get-CIMInstance CIM_ComputerSystem).Name

> The term 'Get-CIMInstance' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Do you know a workaround to execute Get-CIMInstance or Get-WmiObjet with dotnet core using powershell ?

### Update

```
private PSDataCollection<PSObject> InvokeScript(string script)
{

    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        ps.Runspace = runspace;

        ps.AddScript(script);

        ps.Streams.Error.DataAdded += Error_DataAdded;

        PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
        outputCollection.DataAdded += OutputCollection_DataAdded;

        var result = ps.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection);

        foreach (var item in ps.Streams.Error)
        {
            _logger.LogError(item.ToString());
        }

        _logger.LogInformation("Execution has stopped. Execution state: " + ps.InvocationStateInfo.State);

        return outputCollection;
    }
}
```

When i invoke the script `Get-Command`, i found in the result, Get-WmiObject. But when i invoke `Get-WmiObject`, that doesn't run !

Comment: you don't really need `Get-WmiObject`, you can add a reference to `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure` namespace instead... see example using c# from msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-with-c-

Comment: Get-Ciminstance should work with the latest powershell 6 in windows.

Comment: In dotnet core, i use$PSVersionTable.PSVersion, this returns 6.2.2. But Get-Command –module CimCmdlets returns no enlement. How can i import module CimCmdlets ?

Comment: While `Get-CimInstance` works in PowerShell 6, the `CimCmdlets` module was not released with PowerShell 6 **SDK**.

Comment: It is planned to include `CimCmdlets` module in PowerShell 7 SDK. See this issue: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8119

Comment: @GeorgeChakhidze Good news, thanks for your info